# Why in QML TextField on Android character replacements are truncated?

Tags: android, qml, qt6

I create text field for password input in QML with the following code:

```
TextField {
    id: pwdField
    placeholderText: qsTr( "Password" )
    leftPadding: appWindow.minimumCtrlHeight / 3
    echoMode: TextInput.Password
    text: connectScreen.pwd
    selectByMouse: true
    mouseSelectionMode: TextInput.SelectCharacters
    implicitHeight: appWindow.minimumCtrlHeight
    implicitWidth: content.width - 40 - implicitHeight - pwdText.width
    verticalAlignment: TextInput.AlignVCenter
}
```

And the problem is that on Android the character replacement circles are truncated. Look at the picture:

[image: text field]

Is it a known bug of Qt 6.3.1? Or maybe I missed something and this can be fixed?

`appWindow.minimumCtrlHeight` is `Screen.pixelDensity * 8`

Placeholder text is normal, look:

[image: placeholder]

Password in shown mode is ok too:

[image: shown]

Comment: What is `appWindow.minimumCtrlHeight` and why are you sure it's heigh enough to fit the text?

Comment: I answered in the body.

Comment: Maybe you have `clip: true` somewhere?

Comment: Also try dropping this line `implicitHeight: appWindow.minimumCtrlHeight`

Comment: Yes, guys, you are right. Dropping `implicitHeight` solved the problem. Thanks. I will post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the following line:

```
implicitHeight: appWindow.minimumCtrlHeight
```

Dropping this line solved the issue.